# When an option from drop down is selected input type text appears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to implement a function which is , The input type-text is hidden by default and when I select one option (say others) from my drop down view as coded below, I want to unhide/show the input-type text element below it.

```
<select name='property_types' id='property_types' class='postform'>
<option class="level-0" value="Digital screen">Digital Screen</option>
<option class="level-0" value="Lamp poster">Lamp poster</option>
<option class="level-0" value="Bus stand">Bus Stand</option>
<option class="level-0" value="Indoor shopping mall">Indoor shopping mall</option>
<option class="level-0" value="Green belts">Green belts</option>
<option class="level-0" value="showUnhide">others..</option>
</select>
```

and here is code of input type text which I could not show on stack overflow.say its id is "textareaTobeShown". How can I Implement it.

.

Comment: Can you please make jsFiddle ?

Comment: Learn and implement **[jQuery events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/)**

Comment: What do you mean by " which I could not show on stack overflow" - if you can't post exact code due to security reasons, you can always post a sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this will help!

```
<select name='property_types' id='property_types' class='postform' onchange="zz()">


        <option class="level-0" value="Digital screen">Digital Screen</option>

        <option class="level-0" value="Lamp poster">Lamp poster</option>

        <option class="level-0" value="Bus stand">Bus Stand</option>

        <option class="level-0" value="Indoor shopping mall">Indoor shopping  
mall</option>

        <option class="level-0" value="Green belts">Green belts</option>

        <option class="level-0" value="showUnhide">others..</option>

    </select>

    <input type="text" id="textareaTobeShown" style="display:none">


<script>
function zz()
{
var aa=document.getElementById("property_types");
if(aa.value=="showUnhide")
{
document.getElementById('textareaTobeShown').style.display= '';
}
else
{
document.getElementById('textareaTobeShown').style.display= 'none';

}

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume you want to show the `input text` on selecting the option `Green belts`.Refer the following Code

```
  $('#txt').hide(); /*hiding Text Box Initialy*/
  $('#property_types').on('change', function () {
     var value = $(this).val()
     if (value == "Green belts") {
         $('#txt').show();
     } else {
         $('#txt').hide();
     }
 });
```

Please refer the follwing fiddle for the working code:[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/3BZZc/)

Answer (score 0):

your jquery (let your textbox id is **textareaTobeShown**)

```
$('#property_types').on('change',function(){
    var index=$('option:selected',$(this)).index();
    if(index==5){
        $('#textareaTobeShown').show();
    }

    else{
        $('#textareaTobeShown').hide();
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/pJQWA/1/)

Comment: But I am using a framework . i need something to trigger this function.

Comment: @user3765023 what framework..? why didn't you mention it in question? please update the question with proper information to get relevant answers. we can only help you with the info you provide...

Answer (score 0):

Simple jQuery is as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {     
        $('#textareaTobeShown').hide();

        $('#property_types').change(function() {    
            if($(this).val() == "showUnhide"){
                $('#textareaTobeShown').show();
            }
        });
    }); 
</script>
```